# PHP write returnable array to file

Tags: php, arrays, writetofile

I need to read and write an array from/to a file.

The file is filled like this:

```
<?php
    return array(
        'Key' => 'value'
    );
?>
```

I'm already able to read this file using

```
$data = include($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
```

How can i write this array back to the file while keeping the structure of '`<?php return array(); ?>`'?

Comment: Take a look at: `file_put_contents()` + `var_export()`

Comment: Might want to look into xml...

Comment: XML could but i'm only using it myself so readability within the file is not required. An array in this case has less performance influence so XML has no benefit. When the files would be used by non-technical users i would certainly use XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) function:

```
file_put_contents(
    $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file, 
    "<?php\nreturn " . var_export($data, true) . "\n?>"
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do.

Answer (score 1):

better way to store json string in file than again accesss this string to array.

Comment: Doesn't work in this case as the file also gets directly imported to a class from a library. In any other case that would ofcouse be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serialize()` to store an array or object into a string. This code shows how it is done:

```
<?php

$array = ['Key' => 'value'];

$fh = fopen('array.txt','a+');
fwrite($fh,  serialize($array));
fclose($fh);

$read_array = unserialize(file_get_contents('array.txt'));


var_dump($array,$read_array);
/* 
OUTPUTS 

array(1) {
  ["Key"]=>
  string(5) "value"
}
array(1) {
  ["Key"]=>
  string(5) "value"
}
/*
```